# Trying to enter data into mysql database without refreshing the page using php and ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

My html page creates textareas dynamically. I am trying to enter data from these textareas into mysql from the page using Javascript, Ajax and PHP. There is a unique id for each textarea as and when it gets created. The #num button is used to enter the text into database. This is my html code snippet:

```html
<form method="POST">
  <div id ="textFields" class="form-group"> 

            <!--align it all in the center-->
            <p align="center">

            <!--small break-->
            <br>
 
   
            <!--textarea-->
            <textarea id="note0" input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Enter note, max limit 200 words" class="form-control" rows="5"  style="width: 80%;overflow:auto;"></textarea>
                
         

                <!--end of p alignment-->
                </p>

        <!--End of textFields div-->
        </div>

        <!--div for buttons-->
        <div align="left">
            <button id="num" class="w3-button w3-large w3-circle w3-red w3-card-4"  onclick="return false">+</button>
        </div>
  </form>
```

Once the #num button is clicked, a Javascript function is called, which is used along with Ajax so that the page does not refresh and stay the same on click of the #num button. This function is supposed to(or what i am hoping to) pass the values to php page and get the control back after data entry into database.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var note_id = 0;
  

 //on the click of the submit button 
 $("#num").click(function(){
  
  //get the form values
  var inputField = $('<p align="center"><br><textarea id="note' + note_id + '" input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Enter note, max limit 200 words" class="form-control" rows="5" style="width: 80%;overflow:auto;"></textarea></p>');    

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url : "Savenotes.php",
   data : {
    content: $('#note'+note_id).serialize()
    },
   success: function(response)
   {
    alert(response);
        
   }
  });
  
  note_id++;
 });
});
```

And this is the Savenotes.php file which is storing the textarea content into the database:

```html
$Content=$_POST['content'];

$sql_users="INSERT INTO notes(Contentdb) VALUES ('$Content')";
if (mysqli_query($connect,$sql_users))
{
 echo ('Note saved into the database.');
}
else
{
 echo ('Note could not be saved, Please try again!');
 header('Location:finalAppend.html');

}
?>
```

On clicking the #num button, I am not able to get the same data in the database as entered by user in the textarea on the webpage. It only shows "content=" for each entry. How do i get the correct values as entered by the user?

Comment: correct id="note0" in html file

Comment: As `$('#note'+note_id)` is a text field - use `val()`: `content: $('#note'+note_id).val()`

Comment: @u_mulder I tried val() as well, that gives me blank entries in the database

Comment: Are you sure that content is passed to server? What do you see in developers console?

Comment: The developers console shows nothing. Data is not being passed and there is no error. @u_mulder

Comment: So, you need to find out why nothing happens when you click `#num`

Comment: On clicking the #num button, I am not able to get the same data in the database as on the webpage. It enters "content=" for each entry. @u_mulder

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url : "Savenotes.php",
        data : {
            content: $('#note'+note_id).val().serialize()
         },
        success: function(response)
        {
            alert(response);

        }
    });
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var note_id = 0;
  

 //on the click of the submit button 
 $("#num").click(function(){
  
  //get the form values
  var inputField = $('<p align="center"><br><textarea id="note' + note_id + '" input type="text" name="content" placeholder="Enter note, max limit 200 words" class="form-control" rows="5" style="width: 80%;overflow:auto;"></textarea></p>');    

  $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url : "Savenotes.php",
   data : {
    content: $('#note'+note_id).serialize()
    },
   success: function(response)
   {
    alert(response);
        
   }
  });
  
  note_id++;
 });
});
```

Use jQuery instead of $ in above code snippet. And try to run again, And lease let me know its working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

`content: $('#note'+note_id).val()`

istead of 

`content: $('#note'+note_id).serialize()`

Comment: Already tried, val() just gives me blank entries in the database

Comment: Javascript code should work fine, The problem starts from PHP MySql connection, check it.